# php mysql controlling post forms fields

Tags: php, mysql, forms, database-design

I am trying to create a database for storing cars information.

Cars can be categorized as new, used, or for rent.
Each type of car category has different attributes, because new cars have different features that are not needed for used, and same case for used and rent category. Attributes can be added, deleted in future using Application Admin side form manager for these 3 categories.

currently i am storing these in 1 product table with all the attributes required by these 3 categories.

```
PRODUCT(id,title,description,model,kilometer,enginsize,conditions,.....,.,...)
```

As form for each category is proposed to be managed from admin control, i am looking for a new scalable database.

```
current development:

all common attributes in Products

PRODUCT(pid,title,description,...)

CATEGORY(cid,cname) new,used,rent

form_field(formfield_id,name,type)  to store all attributes that are not common

form_field_category(formfield_id,cid) to store category associated attributes

form_post_data(post_id,pid,formfield_id,value) to store submitted data
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How i can divide/organize the PRODUCT table(at the moment store all common and uncommon attributes) that i can avoid NULL values from record, and provide control to add remove attributes for a category(new,used,rent cars.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is called an [Entity-Attribute-Value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).

If most of the values in table `form_post_data` are text, simply make it a `varchar` field. However if you're storing numeric values, choices and other types (things you might want to filter on), have a look at this article [An alternative way of EAV modelling](http://www.jasny.net/articles/an-alternative-way-of-eav-modeling/).

For you have properties that can have multiple values, have a look at this follow up article [EAV multi-value fields](http://www.jasny.net/articles/eav-multi-value-fields/).

Comment: Yes, you are right, and i agreed with you. last day i was unable to find your article for multivalued attributes, today i read all comments in your first article and find the link for multiple valued attributes handling. [Your article](http://www.jasny.net/articles/an-alternative-way-of-eav-modeling/comment-page-1/#comment-353854) is a great debate on this topic and all the commenter contribution make it possible to decide when to use this approach.

Answer (score 1):

for what I understand you have 2 type of attributes: common and category-specific.

So doing something like:

```
PRODUCT(pid,title,description,...)

CATEGORY(cid,cname) new,used,rent

additional_info_category(aid, cid, name)

adition_info_data (adataid, aid, pid, data)
```

Should be enough, you just need to loead all the product info plus the fields in additional info that are related to the category.

You should have no issues adding new fields if they are category-specific but my question is: are you sure you won't need to add common fields?

Comment: Do you think this can be neglect-able. form_field(formfield_id,name,type)  to store all attributes that are not common,,, AS i used it to store All specific attributes, that can be associated to any category.

Comment: I think its easier to have only 1 table `additional_info_category(aid, cid, name)`. If you want to save a attribute not linked to any category, just set cid to `0`.

Comment: Regarding your question, i think there may be some common fields, like MAKE, MODEL.The word COMMON mislead(its my fault),better GENERAL like title, description,status,category, BUT all other attributes will be in additional info.